# jquery reset form after using .before

Tags: jquery, arrays

How can I turn this nested array into a nice html-list?

```
<ul id="droppable">
    <li value="id">lastname firstname</li>
    <li value="id">lastname firstname</li>
</ul>
```

This array is what I get back from my ajaxrequest:

```
[{
    "id": 87,
    "lastname": "BOUSSAUW",
    "firstname": "ANNEMIE"
}, {
    "id": 88,
    "lastname": "VEREENOOGHE",
    "firstname": "STEFAAN"
}, {
    "id": 89,
    "lastname": "VERHEYDEN",
    "firstname": "JOKE"
}]
```

My ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'PHPCalls.php?CallID=GetGroupMembersJSON',
    data: { GroupID : str },
    success: function(data){
        var html = '';
        $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
            html += '<li id="' + obj.id + '">' + obj.lastname + ' ' + obj.firstname + '</li>';
        });

        $('#droppable').html(html);
    }
});
```

EDIT: the ul-tag already existed. No need to add it but I didn't mention

The result I get is a long list of this:

```
<li id="undefined">
    undefined undefined
</li>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to parse the JSON and then iterate over the array.

```
var json = '[{"id": 87,"lastname": "BOUSSAUW","firstname": "ANNEMIE"}, {"id": 88,"lastname": "VEREENOOGHE","firstname": "STEFAAN"}, {"id": 89,"lastname": "VERHEYDEN","firstname": "JOKE"}]';
var data = $.parseJSON(json);

$('#form').html('');

$.each(data, function(i, o) {
    $('#form').append('<li id="'+o.id+'">'+o.lastname+' '+o.firstname+'</li>');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Recode/mDHfs/1/

Comment: After I executed the query in my php-file I did this: echo json_encode($groupmembers); So I suppose the parse is not longer necessary?

Comment: You create a JSON-String with `json_encode($groupmembers);` and you need to parse it on the clientside. I updated my answer.